# How do we calculate difference and percent difference between two columns in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

]Difference and percent Difference must be calculated.

I cannot do Apr20-MAy20 because it is not always the same. I need to show the current month and previous month

So I did a relative filter to just show the current month and previous month.
So the difference of two columns should automatically change when the month changes.

[image]

Now how do I get the same month of prior year, how do I filter ?

I also need to calculate the difference of current year same month and previous year same month.

Thank you in advance for any help!

When I do table across difference, the difference value is overwriting the existing May and Apr month values as the below screen shot, how to show the difference in another column

Currently:
[image]

Below is Expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should create a custom filter for the dates. You want:

- This month this year
- This month last year
- Last month this year

There are a number of ways you could do this. I'll give one example and will assume there aren't any future dates in your data set.

```
[DateFilter]: DATETRUNC('month',[YourDateField])>=DATETRUNC('month',DATEADD('month',-1,TODAY())) OR DATETRUNC('month',[YourDateField])=DATETRUNC('month',DATEADD('year',-1,TODAY()))
```

Put the to the filters shelf, set to True, and it should keep the months you want.

Then you can just use the standard table calculations to [calculate Difference and Percent Difference.](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.htm)

Note, the formula isn't tested, just typed directly into here, let me know if it doesn't work

Based on your comments look at creating separate calculations for to YoY / MoM / etc calculation. That also means creating calculated fields to isolate the Current Month, Previous Month, etc.

For example, the current month:

```
[isCM]: DATETRUNC('month',[YourDateField]) = DATETRUNC('month',TODAY())
```

The previous month:

```
[isPM]: DATETRUNC('month',[YourDateField]) = DATETRUNC('month',DATEADD('month',-1,TODAY()))
```

Then month on month, something like:

```
[MoM]: (SUM([Measure])*INT([isCM]))/(SUM([Measure])*INT([isPM]))
```

To make your table check this article about [using the placeholder technique to create tables in Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/using-the-placeholder-for-advanced-tableau-tables/)

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response Andy. The formula shows current and previous month of current year as expected. I don't have 2019 data in my data set as of now, but I guess the previous year same month will show up once we get the previous year data. For difference calculation- I have measures 'open', 'close' and 'checked' are under the measure values. Sum(Open), sum(Close),Sum(checked). That is the reason I see that data in the visualization. How do I calculate the difference of (current year same month and previous year same month) and (current month and previous month)

Comment: I've updated the answer providing a link for how to do table calculations. This is how you will do the MoM, YoY, etc.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for the link, I want difference to be shown in another column, when I do table(across) difference calculation, this is overwriting the apr20 and May20 values and just showing the difference.

Comment: Andy I have added another screen shot to the question, when I do table(across)difference how I am seeing the values and how I would like the results to be seen, could you please let me know.

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically you need to create a bunch of calculations to do this.

Comment: Andy thanks a lot for your comments, when I try to create MoM calculation, I am getting a syntax error.I tried different ways to fix this, but I couldn't fix it. Can you please let me know:(SUM([Measure])*INT([CurrentMonthCal]))/(SUM([Measure])*[PreviousMonthCalc]))

Comment: I didn't wrap the PreviousMonthCalc in INT. I expect that's the issue. Your error is prob saying something like "expecting integer, getting boolean"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215041/discussion-between-akhira-and-andy-tar-sols).